# Compare two Maps and remove all the elements that either have the same key or the same value

Tags: java, merge, hashmap, unique

I have two Maps that I need to compare and merge them into a result map. I need to remove all the elements that either have the same key or the same value.

Basically, say I have two Maps:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("1", "A");
map1.put("2", "A");
map1.put("3", "B");
map1.put("4", "C");
map1.put("5", "D");
map1.put("6", "E");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("1", "B");
map2.put("2", "A");
map2.put("4", "F");
map2.put("6", "C");
map2.put("7", "G");
map2.put("8", "H");
```

I need to remove all the entries that have either the same keys or the same values and need to retain back only bidirectional unique entries. So after merge, I need to have the following result map in which every key maps to a unique value and every value has a unique key:

```
("5", "D"), ("7", "G"), ("8", "H")
```

What's the best way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I would create another map that contains all the values and keys from map1 and map2, and then I would go through a loop deleting the duplicates keys and values

```
Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);

for(String a: map1.keySet()){
    if(map2.containsKey(a) || map2.containsValue(map1.get(a))){
        map3.remove(a);
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful!

Comment: You should probably iterate over map3 keys!

Comment: Then I will have a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error because I am removing elements from map3

Comment: ah, true! You should maybe use an Iterator with .remove() method then.. but now I realize it's ok just like it is

Comment: Thank you. But this solution won't work if the two maps are reversed. Since we iterate over map1 keys here, any key in map2 will remain in map3 even if they map to a non-unique value.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will do this

```
    Map map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
    map3.keySet().removeAll(map2.keySet());
    map3.values().removeAll(map2.values());
    map2.keySet().removeAll(map1.keySet());
    map2.values().removeAll(map1.values());     
    map3.putAll(map2);
    System.out.println(map3);
```

This will result `{7=G, 5=D, 8=H}`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I can't think of a particularly neat way of doing it but here's a potential solution using Java 8 - I'm pretty sure it could be simplified somewhat. I don't like these sorts of stateful operations mid stream but the only way I can see to avoid it is to split it into two operations.

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> values = new HashSet<>();
Map<String,String> mergedMap =
    Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream)
    .filter(e -> !values.keySet().contains(e.getKey()))
    .filter(e -> !values.valueSet().contains(e.getValue()))
    .peek(e -> values.add(e))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```